# Nodejs - Mongodb/Mongoose retrieve specific field of all users

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a table like the following

```
{ _id: 55db87ed69090a5e4b5515cf,
    firstname: 'Bilbo ',
    lastname: 'Baggins',
    email: 'bilbo@gmail.com',
    points: 0,
    password: '$2a$05$o90atG0rfXQN5X7CLFa59e8QO1PcOcFvH47MXDxVmr2E3id7cSEIG',
    __v: 0 }
```

When I run this I get all the results

```
  User.find({points: req.params.points}, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    });
```

How can I fetch all of the records with the points field?  I want to be able to fetch all points of every user and count them up.

I am quite new to mongodb/mongoose and having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
User.find({points: {$exists: true}}, function(err, docs) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<docs.length; i++) {
        count += docs[i].points;
    }
    console.log('The total of points is: ', count);
});
```

The `{points: {$exists: true}}` query will return only the documents that have that field defined.

Comment: Thankyou that worked great!  I changed int for var though so it would run.

Comment: Oops, I mix languages from time to time. :)
I just edited the answer with that correction.